# Octopus - deploying multiple copies of same service

Tags: powershell, nservicebus, octopus-deploy

I've got an Octopus deployment for an NServiceBus consumer.  Until recently, there's only been one queue to consume.  Now we're trying to get smart about putting different types of messages in different queues.  Right now we've broken that up into 3 queues, but that number might increase in the future.

The plan now is to install the NSB consumer service 3 times, in 3 separate folders, under 3 different names.  The only difference in the 3 deployments will be an `app.config` setting:

```
<add key="NsbConsumeQueue" value="RedQueue" />
```

So we'll have a `Red` service, a `Green` service and a `Blue` service, and each one will be configured to consume the appropriate queue.

What's the best way to deploy these 3 services in Octopus?  My ideal would be to declare some kind of list of services somewhere e.g.

```
ServiceName    QueueName
-----------    ---------
RedService     RedQueue
GreenService   GreenQueue
BlueService    BlueQueue
```

and loop through those services, deploying each one in its own folder, and substituting the value of `NsbConsumeQueue` in `app.config` to the appropriate value.  I don't think this can be done using variables, which leaves PowerShell.

Any idea how to write a PS script that would do this?

Comment: Hi Saul :)  Can you give a little more background why you are would want 3 separate queues for the same message types?  Are you trying to prioritize message handling?

Comment: They are different message types.  Nice to see you here @TylerDay!  Were you stalking me, or did you just happen to see my post?  :)

Comment: Just happened to stumble upon this.  I started using NSB about a year ago.   I don't know octopus deploy, but I think you will probably have to go the powershell route.  That's what I've been doing for my deployments.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use the same 'consumer' for three different endpoints? I have a different endpoint (+ project) for each endpoint that can host multiple AC's, depending on which AC from which Service I host in that endpoint. I can see value in both methods, just curious why you chose to go down that route.

Answer (score 1):

At my previous employer, we used the following script to deploy from Octopus:
http://www.layerstack.net/blog/posts/deploying-nservicebus-with-octopus-deploy

Add the two Powershell scripts to your project that contains the NServiceBus host. Be sure to [override the host identifier](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/override-hostid) or ServicePulse will go mad, because every deployment gets its own folder, due to Octopus.

But as mentioned in the comments, be sure that you're splitting endpoints for the right reason. We also had/have at least 4 services, but that's because we have a logical separation. For example, we have a finance service where all finance messages go to. And a sales service where all sales services go to. This follows the DDD bounded context principle and is there for reasons. I hope your services aren't actually called red, green and blue! :)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful!  A few requests: (1) Can you please insert the important excerpts of the linked pages?  Over time, hyperlinks get broken, and we want SO to be useful to future programmers for decades to come.  (2) If you can add in the syntax for defining a collection of service name/queue name pairs and looping through them, that would also be super-useful, as well as substituting the correct value in each config file.  (And no, rest assured my services are *not* called Red, Green and Blue!)

Answer (score 1):

Powershell should not be needed for this.  Variables in Octopus can be scoped to a step in the deployment process.  So you could have 3 steps, one for each service, and 3 variables for the queue names, each scoped to one of the steps.

You could also add variables for the service names, and use those variables in the process step settings.  That would let you see both the service names and queue names from the variables page.

Comment: Yes, but what if I go really micro-service on this, and break NServiceBus out into 100 different queues?  I don't want to make 100 steps in Octopus.  Actually make that 400, since I have (1) stop service, (2) uninstall service, (3) install service and (4) start service steps.  That's why I want to be able to loop.

Comment: @ShaulBehr if you have 400 micro services, I'd assume you don't want to deploy them all at the same time anyway since they''re microservices. You'll then probably only deploy a small amount of them, which even though it is annoying probably is better suited for extra steps. Stop and uninstall service can be a pre-deployment script, install service the deployment and start service the post-deployment, making every micro service one step.

Comment: The perfect solution for me, thanks.  It assumes you don't have too many steps though!